# HTTP status code 200 vs 202

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-status-codes

I have a `Python`+`requests` script.

*Steps that script should execute*:

- send file to DB;
- approve this file (change file state in DB);
- download file.

*The constraint*:

**Only approved file could be downloaded**

*My code*:

```
requests.post(url_to_create, files={"file": open(path_to_file)})
requests.post(url_to_approve, data={'id': file_id})
requests.get(url_to_download, data={'id': file_id})
```

*The problem*:

This code works almost perfectly, but sometimes I get no file. I found that the first and the third requests return `200` status code while the second returns `202`. As I understand (tell me if I wrong) status `202: Accepted` means that server accept request and return status code without actual request completion

*The question*:

Does it mean that request to download could be send even if request to approve hasn't been already completed and, if it is so, how can I wait till approval-request completed before send download-request?

Comment: Afaik that should not be possible. The Response.content property will block until the entire response has been downloaded.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends on your server implementation and your server decides how `202` will be processed.

> **202 Accepted**
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
>   not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted
>   upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
>   There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous
>   operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to
>   allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
>   batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
>   requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until
>   the process is completed. The entity returned with this response
>   SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and
>   either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user
>   can expect the request to be fulfilled.

If response body is empty, makes sense to check response headers that should have additional information.

**Reference** - https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html